# Select nr of occurrences in table column

Tags: php, mysql

I have a site where users selects which team will win a sports match

**What I want to do**

I want to count the number of times each team was selected

**Example:**

5 users selected manchester united, 3 users selected liverpool, 8 users selected Chelsea and so on

**My problem**

I am struggling to find the correct query to execute the above

I have tried the following

```
SELECT pick, COUNT(pick) AS pickNR FROM multiple_picks WHERE round = '3' AND tournament ='Super RUgby' GROUP BY round_game_nr
```

But it returns incorrect results as can be seen from  the image below, since not each team has been selected 6 times.

[image]

My Table format can be seen from the image below

[image]

If anyone can advise me what I am doing wrong, or point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. The end goal is to get the number of times each team was selected, and add it to a php variable and insert it into a chart library, but I just need to get the query right.

Comment: `member_nr`  is the id of the user and `round_game_nr` is the id of the team ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix `member_nr` is the userId, the person who made the pick, `round_game_nr` is the number of the game in the round, i.e round 3 has 5 games and so on.....makes sense?

Comment: one more question. How do you add a pick ? For ex. when a member picks a  team how do you insert it or update already existing row ?

Comment: @VasilShaddix no I insert it, a user can only make 1 pick per round...I've uploaded an example image for you

Comment: @VasilShaddix see image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting a different column which is not in `GROUP BY` clause. You are grouping by `round_game_nr` and selecting `pick`. I hope pick is the team name.

```
SELECT pick, COUNT(round_game_nr) AS pickNR
FROM multiple_picks WHERE round = '3' AND tournament ='Super RUgby' 
GROUP BY pick
```

Comment: Thank you very much for answer, im gonna try query and let you know in 2 mins, `pick` is indeed the team name

Comment: Yeah, sure. Let me know if some problem pertains.

Comment: Bydaway do you know of any good, easy to use, PHP library that I can use   to display this data in a chart?

Comment: Sorry,not worked in PHP much, but you can find many on SO who can help

Comment: ...except that such questions are off-topic for SO